# Switchable and size changing custom loss function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm working on a multi-task multi-label classifier, all should be done in the same network (sharing weights). I want to train the network in the following switchable manner:

```
if batch_type=1 => train with data minibatch X and labels of size (batchsize,**2**) (labels: 0/1)  

if batch_type=2 => train with data minibatch X and labels of size (batchsize,**2**) (labels: A/B)

if batch_type=3 => train with data minibatch X and labels of size (batchsize,**3**) (labels: a/b/c)
```

I know that I can implement a custom loss function and include K.switch in it (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684768/customize-keras-loss-function-in-a-way-that-the-y-true-will-depend-on-y-pred)), but then I run into a problem of different sizes of `y_pred` and `y_true` (between the cases above).

Any ideas how to do it?

[Edit] It seems that I oversimplified my question, so I will try to explain it better here: I have three tasks on the same data (X). Each sample of my data is a sequence. Each sequence is either positive or negative (0/1 task 1 above). Each **negative** sample is either A/B (task 2) **AND** a/b/c (task 3). In order to train the system together (assuming it will benefit from sharing the wights), I could introduce a single input X and single combined softmax (0Aa,0Ab,...) or 3 separated softmax layers (0/1,A/B,a/b/c). In both cases, it's terribly hard to balance my single minibatch X to have 50%/50% 0/1 **AND** 50%/50% A/B **AND** 33%/33%/33# a/b/c. This is why I chose to train it with 3 inputs (X_01,X_AB,X_abc) each is balanced in respect to its type and three output nodes (y_01,y_AB,y_abc). This solution technically compiles and runs, but it's neither stable nor beneficial (performance wise). This is why I'm trying to make it "switchable" as I explained above.

Comment: What are the shapes of each batch_type?

Comment: I thought it should be int so (1x1)

Comment: So, how will you identify what type of batch it is?

Comment: That's not a problem. Look here:https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2121

Answer (score 0):

The link you refer to is very old, it's for Keras 1.0. Now we are at 2.1.3 that would give a completely different answer to that old question. I only briefly scanned the paper but I can't see different output shapes mentioned.

In current version of Keras output size of any layer is a model level setting. This means it is not possible to do what you ask on the way you plan to do it.

Nevertheless it can be achieved by using vanilla Keras.
You can combine your outputs like this [0Aa, 0Ab, ..., 1Bb, 1Bc]
Then you can build a [DAG](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Directed_acyclic_graph) with a merging dense layer at the end.
First tower should return [0/1], second [A/B], third [a/b/c]. If desired, layers can be shared so that only the output layers need to be different. The last layer should be a softmax of each tower with shape 2, 2, 3 in order corresponding to your types. 3 auxiliary outputs should be used to keep control of training the 3 towers.
Then you can put a final softmax layer to combine with shape 12 (2 x 2 x 3 = 12).
This can be done only via the [Functional API of Keras](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

This way you can build any **multi-label classifier in Keras**.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Actually, this is exactly what I'm doing (without the combined softmax in the end) but it doesn't seem to work that well. I edited my question to better reflect my needs.